# For a real number $x$, prove that for $f(x)= \frac{\tan \pi [x-\pi])}{1+[x]^2}$, $f’(x)$ exists for all $x$. [.] is GIF

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I don’t know how to is start this. Calculation left hand and right hand derivative is cumbersome because no particular value of $x$ is given. The function doesn’t appear to be continuous at integral values but according to graph it is. Can I get a hint on how to solve this?

Edit

Let the function be $f(x) = h(x).g(x)$

$h(x)$ is discontinues at $x=\pi$ and$g(x)$ is discontinuous at $1,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3..$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

$[x-\pi]$ is an integer and $\tan (n\pi)=0$ for any integer $n$. Hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is of the form $\tan(nπ)=0$ where n is an integer. Hence $f(x)=0 \forall x$ and $f'(x)=0 \forall x$ as well.